# Why We Don't Need To Import the java.lang package to use the Integer Class(Wrapper Classes) In Java

Tags: java

Suppose i want to make the object of an **Integer**(not int) Class,Since the Integer Class is in another package, i should have to import the java.lang package for creating the object of the **Integer Class**.But I didn't import the package ,yet compiler doesn't give me an error.

Comment: `java.lang` is automatically imported for you.

Comment: For convenience, the Java compiler automatically imports three entire packages for each source file: (1) the package with no name, (2) the java.lang package, and (3) the current package (the package for the current file).

Comment: A nearly exact duplicate on software engineering site: [Why we don't import a package while we use String functions?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148230/44705)

Comment: Because of [JLS #7 Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html): 'A compilation unit automatically has access to all types declared in its package and also automatically imports all of the public types declared in the predefined package java.lang.' Duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is defined in [Chapter 7 of the Java Language Specification (JLS)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html):

> A compilation unit [...] automatically imports all of the `public` types declared in the predefined package `java.lang`.